# Two mysql selects in one query - one after another

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have a mysql table like this:

```
+----+------+
| id | rank |
+----+------+
| 1  | 2    |
+----+------+
| 2  | -1   |
+----+------+
| 3  | 5    |
+----+------+
| 4  | 1    |
+----+------+
| 5  | -1   |
+----+------+
| 6  | -1   |
+----+------+
| 7  | 8    |
+----+------+
| 8  | -1   |
+----+------+
```

Now I want to get the ids in the following order: At first

```
WHERE rank >= 1 ORDER BY rank ASC
```

and afterwards:

```
WHERE rank = -1
```

How can I get this in only one `mysql_query()`?

Comment: why not write 2 queries?

Comment: ORDER BY CASE WHEN rank>=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1,rank

Comment: Complicated. Rest of the code structure expects just one query. If I can't find a solution, I will edit it and use two querys. But that will be a lot of work, so better ask before. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE rank >= 1
ORDER BY rank
UNION
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE rank = -1
```

OR something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE rank >= 1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN rank>=1 
              THEN 0 
              ELSE 1,rank
```

Answer (score 0):

**Proposed answer:**

```
SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE rank >= 1 ORDER BY rank ASC
UNION
SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE rank = -1
```

From my understanding, you wanted a column of id's, starting with the ids `WHERE rank >= 1 ORDER BY rank ASC` and ending with the ids `WHERE rank = -1`.

The previous sql query uses `UNION` which joins two resulting tables from separate `SELECT` queries. `UNION` can only be applied when you have the same mount of generated columns from each `SELECT` query, so that's a good thought to keep in mind if later you want to increase the amount of columns obtained.

Answer (score 0):

You can also map rank with ELT.

**sample**

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ELT(rank+2,99,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) ASC;
```